# Pandas: Conver all strings in column to 1

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with a column df.open. I want to check this column for strings. If there's a string, I'd like to convert it to a 1. There are already a lot of 1s and 0s in the column.

So, suppose the values in the column are as follows: <0,0,1,0,text,1,open,0,0,xyz,1>. I'd like to go through the column and turn all strings (i.e. 'text', 'open', 'xyz') into 1s.

One thing I was thinking was to convert numeric. Then, where ever there's a NaN, convert that to a 1. But that seems silly...

Comment: "If there's not a string, I'd like to convert it to a 0" vs. "There are already a lot of 1s and 0s in the column." -- so, pre-existing 0s and 1s should all be 0 afterwards? Or what does "If there's not a string, I'd like to convert it to a 0" mean exactly?

Comment: Thanks. I suppose that's not clear. Suppose the values in the column are as follows: <0,0,1,0,text,1,open,0,0,xyz,1>. I'd like to go through the column and turn all strings (i.e. 'text', 'open', 'xyz') into 1s.

Answer (score 2):

Convert all to boolean then to int:

```
df.open = df.open.astype(bool).astype(int)
```

`1` and any non-empty text is `True`, `0` is `False`.

`True` is `1`, `False` is `0`.

Comment: Thanks. Quick question: what would this do to the existing 1s and 0s?

Comment: @user3347713 it converts `1`s to `True` then to `1`, and `0` to `False` then to `0`.

Comment: Hmm.. So, it looks like many of my existing 1 and 0 are actually in there as '0' or '1', so they're all getting converted to 1...

Answer (score 1):

**In short,** first create a mask and then use this mask for indexing to change values in place:

```
boolmask_nonumbers = np.isnan(df.open.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True))
df.open[boolmask_nonumbers] = 1
```

**Longer explanation:**

The test object, a Series (which essentially is a column in a DataFrame):

```
>>> s = pd.Series([1, 0, "foo", 1])
>>> s
0      1
1      0
2    foo
3      1
dtype: object
```

Note that it is of type `object`, indicating the mixture of data types. Use pandas' built-in function [convert_objects](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html) to convert values to numeric values, leaving those which are *not* numeric as `NaN`s:

```
>>> s_num = s.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
>>> s_num
0     1
1     0
2   NaN
3     1
dtype: float64
```

As you can see, the data type changed to `float64`. Now let's set all NaNs to 1, via bool indexing, making use of numpy's `isnan()` function:

```
>>> s_num[np.isnan(s_num)] = 1
```

There you are:

```
>>> s_num
0    1
1    0
2    1
3    1
```

**Edit**

This approach is a little too generic for your data, because it also handles floats. The trick that eumiro uses, to evaluate all of your values as booleans, and to then convert back to integer, serves a significant speedup.

His approach, working on a column with 10^6 items, takes about 4 seconds for 100 iterations on my machine:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("s=pd.Series(samples); s = s.astype(bool).astype(int)", setup="import numpy as np; import pandas as pd; import random as rd; values = [1, 0, 'lol']; samples = [rd.choice(values) for _ in xrange(10**6)]", number=100)
3.974711554180317
```

My approach takes almost 10 times as long:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("s=pd.Series(samples); s[np.isnan(s.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True))]=1", setup="import numpy as np; import pandas as pd; import random as rd; values = [1, 0, 'lol']; samples = [rd.choice(values) for _ in xrange(10**6)]", number=100)
30.0552612268267
```

Given durations include data creation, which takes that long:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("s = pd.Series(samples)", setup="import numpy as np; import pandas as pd; import random as rd; values = [1, 0, 'lol']; samples = [rd.choice(values) for _ in xrange(10**6)]", number=100)
1.694933953806128
```

That is, with eumiro's approach the data creation takes about as long as data processing.

Comment: This is very helpful. Now, if I want to carry this out over, say 30+ columns, would this be my code?

df.iloc[:, 30:61] = df.iloc[:, 30:61].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
df.iloc[:, 30:61][np.isnan(df.iloc[:, 30:61])] = 1

Comment: Interesting: when I run this over df.iloc[:, 30:61], there are still NaNs in some of the columns...

Comment: Glad to have been of help, but you might want to give a vote then. This is how it works here. ;). Your second question is not clear enough.